# Doubt about the power of $x$ of the function to find that $f(x) = 3$ is an even function

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

Using the definition of even functions, $f(-x) = f(x) = 3$, hence it is an even function.

Also, it is being mentioned that *if $f(x)$ is an even power of $x$, then it is an even function of $x$. Same for an odd function.*

We know that the equation of a horizontal line in slope-intercept form is $y = mx + b$ where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept.

That means, the equation of the horizontal line $y = 3$ can be written as,

$y = 0x^1 + 3$

where $m = 0$ and *b = 3*.

Therefore,

$y = f(x) = 0x^1 + 3 = 0x^1 + 3x^0$

Now, what is the power of the function above, *$0$ or $1$*?

I want to apply the even power method to determine whether $f(x) = 3$ is an even function or let any function having multiple terms with $x^n$ to determine whether it is an even function (or an odd function let's say) just by using the power method.

Comment: When you say "power", I hope you mean degree. The degree of $f$ is 0. And, by convention, degree of the zero polynomial is taken to be $-\infty$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak See my first comment on PrincessEev's answer

Comment: @Charlie_23: Hi! Your question body doesn't seem to be asking the same thing your title is. If you actually want people to help you show that $f(x)$ is even, please clarify, thanks! ¶ By the way, the fact that an odd power of $x$ is an odd function and an even function of $x$ is an even function is not generally treated as part of the *definition* of even and odd functions; it is just a consequence. If your source treats it as part of the definition, that's unusual enough that I would recommend you edit your question to indicate what that source is.

Comment: @BrianTung Hey. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I have edited the question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we say the degree of a polynomial is given by the largest power of $x$ with a nonzero coefficient.

> ***Technical Aside:*** In relevant contexts, this is often given a few caveats (probably beyond the scope of this thread). For instance:
>
> - The polynomial should be written in the standard form $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n$.
> - If you do not like the choice of $a_0 x^0$ as a valid interpretation of the constant coefficient (to ensure that constant functions are of degree $0$), you would have to insist upon it by convention, i.e. *define from the outset* that the degree of such polynomials is $0$ (or use a clunky definition that ultimately is just an obfuscation of such).
> - The degree of the all-zero polynomial is somewhat contentious as an additional special case of the previous bullet; I've seen people give it degrees of $0$ and $-\infty$ in the past; others evidently just do not assign it one whatsoever.

Hence, $x^2$ and $x^2 + 0x^3 + 0x^4 + 0x^{100}$ are both degree-$2$ polynomials.

We interpret the constant-function case as a polynomial of degree $0$ (hence even).

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the power of $x$ in $f(x) = ^2 + 0^3 + 0^4 + 0^100$ is its degree?
Also, for the degree of a polynomial, the power of $x$ in the leading term should be greater than zero along with its nonzero coefficient. And a constant function have the power of $x$ equals $0$. So, how can we talk about its degree then? I am insisting on slope intercept form of the horizontal line.

Comment: Consider  the polynomial $$P(x):=x^2+3x^7-3x^7$$ The coefficients are all non-zero, however $\,\deg {P(x)}≠7\,$. I guess, you mean that  *degree of a polynomial in standard form* .

Comment: "Thanks. Do you mean the power of $x$ in $f(x)=x^2+0x^3+0x^4+0x^{100}$ is its degree?" -- Specifically the *largest* power of $x$, which has a *nonzero* coefficient. $x^2$ is that, so $2$ (the power in question) is its degree.

Comment: the $0$ polynomial is constant yet is not assigned a degree.

Comment: "the power of $x$ in the leading term should be greater than zero along with its nonzero coefficient" -- The powers of $x$ don't have to be strictly positive if you don't want them to be. But if you wish to insist upon that, then you will have to insist upon the convention that constant polynomials have degree $0$ (perhaps with degree $-\infty$ for the constant-zero function, for reasons beyond the scope of this thread).

Comment: @PrincessEev Thanks.

Comment: @lonestudent yes, in *standard form*.

Comment: @PrincessEev " Also, for the degree of a polynomial, the power of 
 in the leading term should be greater than zero along with its *nonzero* coefficient." Sorry,  my bad. I meant *nonnegative coefficient* where the leading term is $a_nx^n$.

Answer (score 1):

the power of the function 0^1+3^0 is 0- since it's the one with a nonzero coefficient. So when checking for any polynomial eqn- remember to take into account their coefficients- they have to be nonzero

Comment: Agreed. Note that the function $f(x)=0$ is usually said either to not have a degree, or to have degree $-\infty.$ It is also a "constant" function, but it is only *nonzero* constant functions which have degree $0.$ [these are a bit nit-picky points but need to be followed in order to make certain general statements hold.